# Why are Bell states the maximally entangled ones?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, bell-basis

I just want to know why actually Bell states are examples of maximally entangled states and significance of that "maximal" term. Is there anything for proving that?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you want to take as your definition of maximally entangled. But, here's a good one:

> Given a Bell state, I can convert it into any other two-qubit
> entangled state using only local operations and classical
> communication

Given that local operations and classical communication cannot increase entanglement, the possibility of performing $|\psi\rangle\rightarrow|\phi\rangle$ naturally induces a partial ordering of states being more or less entangled than each other, and the Bell states sit at the top of that tree.

---

Proof of my claim: let's say I start with $(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. I apply a measurement, which comprises two operators
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \beta \end{array}\right)\otimes I,\qquad \left(\begin{array}{cc} \beta & 0 \\ 0 & \alpha \end{array}\right)\otimes I.
$$
If I get the second outcome, I apply $X$ on both qubits (this requires classical communication). Thus, whichever result I get, I have the output
$$
\alpha|00\rangle+\beta|11\rangle.
$$
If I choose $\alpha,\beta$ to be the two Schmidt coefficients of my target state, I'm done, up to local unitary rotations.

Comment: But by saying "*cannot increase entanglement*", you might suppose the amount of entanglement first.

Comment: @narip I don't agree. I'm starting from a qualitative definition, that entanglement is something generated from the interaction between two remote parties, and cannot be generated locally. From there, my argument is telling you that there is a partial ordering, and makes it quantifiable.

Comment: That's very nice! I didn't know that LOCC can reduce the amount of entanglement. But this is solely due to measurements, right?

Comment: @WeatherReport Yes, exactly. Local unitaries preserve the amount of entanglement. Measurements, on average, reduce entanglement (although individual results can increase the entanglement)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But now you provoked an additional question:) How can a local measurement increase entanglement? Say in a system of two qubits if I measure one of them it will be in a definite state, so not at all entangled with the other one.

Comment: @NikitaNemkov You are perhaps thinking of projective measurements. But generalised measurements give a greater range of freedom. Consider $(|00\rangle+2|11\rangle)/\sqrt{5}$ and use two measurement operators $\text{diag}(1,1/2)$ and $\text{diag}(0,\sqrt{3}/2)$. The first gives a maximally entangled output, the second gives a fully separable output. You might like to look up "Entanglement of Pure States for a Single Copy" by Vidal.

Comment: That's fascinating! So by entangling one of my qubits with an auxiliary system and measuring the latter, there is a probability to obtain a state of my qubits that is even more entangled than before? I see that in your ref. Vidal quantifies this probability, but unfortunately he does not use the language of generalized measurement which makes it a bit hard for me to follow. Anyway, thanks a lot for this discussion!

Answer (score 6):

Entanglement is analogous to correlation.

Correlation over a property simply exists where *simultaneous determination is not equivalent to individual determination of a property*. What does it mean?

Say you have 2 coins - one black and one white. Let's say if you have a black coin you get a $+1$ colour value whereas with white you get a $-1$ colour value. If you *randomly* distribute these coins to two people $A$ and $B$ and one person looks at a coin, they will immediately know the *colour* of the other coin. How? Well because if you have a colour, say white, you can *exactly* determine what colour the other person has ( although you may not convey that to them ).

Continuing with our example, let's say $v_a$ is the value $A$ expects to gain and $v_b$ is the value $B$ expects to gain. Since the distribution was random, the average value of $v_a$ is $0$ and similarly, the average value of $v_b$ is $0$. What is the average of $v_a v_b$? It is just $-1$ because the product is always going to be $-1$. What does it mean?

This means the average value ($+1\ or\ -1$) of the property i.e. colour value is *correlated*. Why? Because the average of the product i.e. $-1$ ( simultaneous determination ) is not equivalent to the product of the averages i.e. $0$.

A qubit $q_i$ is said to be entangled with qubit $q_j$ if determining the state of $q_i$ lets us know *some* information about the state of $q_j$. *Maximal* entanglement here means that determining the state of one qubit lets you **completely** determine the state of the other qubit. Moreover, if you only try to measure a single state, you would randomly get either a value of $0$ or $1$ and no useful information about the *individual systems*.

The four bell states are -
$$ | \psi_1 \rangle = \frac{|00\rangle + |11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\\
   | \psi_2 \rangle = \frac{|01\rangle + |10\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\\
   | \psi_3 \rangle = \frac{|01\rangle - |10\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\\
   | \psi_4 \rangle = \frac{|00\rangle - |11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Since the correlation between states of the two qubits is maximum, we say that the states are *maximally entangled* and simple visual proof for this is that for any Bell State, measuring one qubit *completely determines* what the state of the other qubit will be!

If you carefully see, in any of the four states, if you measure let's say qubit 1, you have a **complete knowledge** of what the state of qubit 2 is going to be after your measurement. Eg. in $|\psi_2 \rangle$ you see a measurement of qubit 1 completely determines the state of qubit 2 i.e. if qubit 1 is measured as $0$, qubit 2 would surely be measured as $1$ and vice versa.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer

Comment: Good answer and I like it!

Comment: @gIS Moderators, I'm sorry I think someone has hacked my account and answered some questions using ChatGPT. I'm really sorry for this unhealthy discussions. I'm attemoting to delete this account. –